# Run BAT files from other BAT files?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple .bat files for the same program w/ different parameters. Is this possible?

Here is what I have right now:

```
@echo off
Cls
color 0A
echo title
PAUSE
:Main
color 0A
Cls
echo 1 : name1.bat
echo 2 : name2.bat
echo 3 : name3.bat
set /p file=Enter the number of the file you want to run:
Cls
```

Would something like this work? what would I need to do to get this to run a bat file when its number is entered?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this problem. The shortest (simplest) one is: 1- Make sure that the user can only enter valid input values via `choice` command, and 2- Name all Batch files with fixed-format names (like the ones in your example) and call the appropriate one directly.

```
@echo off
Cls
color 0A
echo title
PAUSE
:Main
color 0A
Cls
echo 1 : name1.bat
echo 2 : name2.bat
echo 3 : name3.bat
choice /C:123 /M:"Enter the number of the file you want to run: "
call name%errorlevel%.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have condition loops. you can test the variable value and execute in the following manner. you can also use a `call` statement as well.

```
IF "%file%" EQU "1" ( 
       name1.bat
   )
   IF "%file%" EQU "2" ( 
       name2.bat
   )
   IF "%file%" EQU "3" ( 
       name3.bat
   )
```

Comment: You must `call` other batch files, otherwise control won't be returned to the calling batch file after the called batch terminates.

Comment: This includes unnecessary indents and commands why not use the simpler versions that are listed above.. They are easier to understand and have self explanatory commands .. I am sure they work too

Answer (score 0):

Current .bat file is running in C drive and you want to run .bat file placed in D: directory then in first .bat write.

```
D:
cd "D:/folder/folder2/"
call batFile.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i assume that you want to start batch file of the users choice
     Here is the code  :

```
   @echo off
   Cls
   color 0A
   echo title
   PAUSE
 :Main
   color 0A
   Cls
   echo 1 : name1.bat
   echo 2 : name2.bat
   echo 3 : name3.bat
   set /p file=Enter the number of the file you want to run
   if %file%==1 start name1.bat
   if %file%==2 start name2.bat
   if %file%==3 start name3.bat
   goto end
 :end
    echo File is now running!
     pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the goto option:

```
@echo off
Cls
color 0A
echo title
PAUSE
:Main
color 0A
Cls
echo 1 : name1.bat
echo 2 : name2.bat
echo 3 : name3.bat
set /p file=Enter the number of the file you want to run:
Cls
GOTO %file%

:1
start name1.bat
exit

:2
start name2.bat
exit

:3
start name3.bat
exit
```